# FB connect with Three20 - problem logging in facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, three20, fbconnect

I've started using Three20 and building a FB connect iPhone iOS app,

I'm trying to call `[facebook authorize:permissionsArray delegate:self];`

but it doesn't do anything, because the functions of FB trying to add subviews to the main window which doesn't exist in Three20 apps. I've tried to use safari authentication but it won't return to my app and complete the process.

Is there any other way signing in FB account via Three20 iOS apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the Safari authentication you are mentioning is the single sign on feature of the Facebook API.  It just manifests itself as Safari if you are in the Simulator.  If you are on a physical device w/ the Facebook App installed it will forward you to an authorization page in Facebook, or if already authorized will simply log you in.

I believe the piece you're missing on the single sign on is setting up a callback URL and registering that URL for your app in the .plist app configuration file.

Facebook has a pretty detailed tutorial on getting everything setup:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios

> A specific URL needs to be registered
>   in this file that uniquely identifies
>   the app with iOS. Create a new row
>   named URL types with a single item,
>   URL Schemes, containing a single
>   value, fbYOUR_APP_ID (the literal
>   characters fb followed by your app
>   id).

I'm also using the Three20 framework and the Facebook SDK and both should work fine together.  Though there are enough steps to getting the Facebook SDK up and running that first time that it's a bit tricky to get going.

Comment: Another question - the fbDidLogin method isn't provoked when the process is done. Any other option doing something after the login has finished? Thanks!

Comment: Two things to check:  Make sure your App is handling the url callback from the Facebook SSO, in your main app delegate you need to define the method:  `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`  Also ensure the object where you are using the facebook instance implements the protocol `FBSessionDelegate` and that you correctly set the delegate on the facebook instance when calling authorize: `[facebook authorize:kAppId permissions:permissions delegate:self];`

Comment: Ok solved it. I've merged the same method in the app delegate that contained `[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:URL.absoluteString]]` and added `return [facebook handleOpenURL:URL]` and after deleting the first line it's working great. But isn't any problem of removing this line? Thanks.

Comment: You know I haven't tried calling an app url (i.e. fb12345://) via the `TTNavigator openURLAction:` method, but based on what you described that call looks it's calling your app over and over again.  Thus your infinite loop.  There shouldn't be an issue, as the line `[facebook handleOpenURL:URL]` is what really needs to be called for you login to complete.